# Backgroundworker in C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Actually, i need to prompt a loading image throwugh backgrounderworker,  whenever a particular function is been invoked 
here is my code :

```
 private void bgwFile_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
        FormFieldsLoad();      
 }

private void bgwFile_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
    {
        Status.Text = "cancelled";
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
    }

    picprocess.SendToBack(); 
    Status.Text = "Completed";         
}

 //Below Method where i have called RunWorkerAsync()
private void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadFile(pdfFullPath, txtPassword.Text);
    form = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    java.util.List FieldTypes = form.getFields();
    availableFieldsTable.Clear();
    btnLoad.Enabled = false;     
    Status.Text = "Document loaded successfully!!!";

    picprocess.BringToFront();  
    bgwFile.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

while running the above code , it invokes the loading image but no output is being displayed it keeps on displaying the loading image .. it is not calling up the  `RunWorkerCompleted`

Can any one help me out pls

Thanks

Comment: What the FormFieldsLoad method does?

Comment: @laszlokiss88  it identifies the form fields present in pdf form and loads up in datatable

Comment: Did you debug i to confirm RunWorkerCompleted is not called? I suspect it is calling it, but picprocess.SendToBack() does not what you think it does. Did you try `picprocess.Visible = false` ?

Comment: yeah i have debugged it it , it fails to call the bgwFile_RunWorkerCompleted method.. let me try using 'picprocess.Visible' = false

Comment: May be it is going in the error block. You see, you are not doing anything there. Put a prompt or status like "Completed with error" there to view the error.

Comment: @NULL Nope it fails .. even though when i add picprocess.Visible = false

Comment: @Murtuza I tried with adding up messagebox inside error block ,, no  differences

Comment: Perhaps FormFieldsLoad is not finishing (infinite or deadlock).  We can't know since you haven't shown us.

Comment: @Ganeshja are the events properly hooked up? (go to the properties of you BackGroundWorker and check the events tab) Also try removing FormFieldsLoad();

Answer (score 3):

Did you assign the event handlers?

```
bwgFile.DoWork += bgwFile_DoWork;
bwgFile.RunWorkerCompleted += bgwFile_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

Are you sure `FormFieldsLoad` terminates?

Answer (score 0):

As @Rik said, have you assigned the event handler?

If you have, put a break point or other trace to verify that your `bgwFile_DoWork` method execute as you expect and aren't getting stuck in an infinite loop or something.

Answer (score 0):

Does DoWork actually finishes? Will this code print anything in the output window?

```
 private void bgwFile_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
        FormFieldsLoad();      
        Console.WriteLine("Work done");
 } // <-or put a breakpoint here
```